# VIEW JPEG and PDF together in Forge 2D viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there any documentation for converting a JPEG file via Model Derivative API and viewing it as an underlay of another 2D PDF drawing, in Forge 2D Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

JPEG files aren't supported accordingly to this [page](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/). PDF is supported and translating a PDF is not different from other file types. Here is a [step by step documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/) to do it.

Now back on JPEG, the Model Derivative API will not handle JPEG format, but you can still display JPEG in the Autodesk Forge Viewer using native THREE.JS API. All you need to do is to assign the JPEG to a THREE.JS mesh and add the mesh to the THREE.JS scene in the Viewer.